# How to duplicate header in checkout pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've three headers in my theme, and i theming the shop with my theme using templates overriding default templates.

i've this in my header.php

Header 1: For my Home site (Not shop)

Header 2: For all pages of my site (Not shop)

Header 3: For shop (Product Categories, single product, archive product)

But, when i buy any product, i go to any checkout page (Register, Cart, My Account, etc), Header 2 appears.

Simplified header.php code:

```
if(!is_woocommerce()) {
   <!--Header Wordpress-->
   if(is_home);
      Home site header (Header 1)
   } else {
      All site header (except Home) (Header 2)
   <!--End Header Wordpress-->
} else { // Woocommerce conditional
   Shop header (Header 3)
}
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cart and checkout are standard pages with short codes and aren't included in the other Woo templates, i.e. `is_woocommerce()` won't return true for them. So perhaps use

```
if ( is_page( 'checkout-page-slug' ) || is_page( 'other_shop_page' ) ) {
```

instead to target them.

**Edit:**

Replace `checkout-page-slug` or `other_shop_page` with the [slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Slug) of a page you want to target to have the shop header:

```
if ( ! is_woocommerce() ) {
    if ( is_home() ) {
        // Home site header (Header 1)
    } elseif( is_page( 'checkout-page-slug' ) || is_page( 'other_shop_page' ) ) {
        // Shop header
    } else {
       // All site header (except Home) (Header 2)
    }
} else { // Woocommerce conditional
    // Shop header
}
```

Comment: @MrRoman -- I've added an expanded example using your original code snippet. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: can i use an array in is_page()? example 'is_page(array('slug-1', 'slug-2', 'slug-3'))'

Comment: @MrRoman - Yes you can (and should) if you're going to have more than three pages that you'd wish to check.

Comment: Thank you very much and excuse my english. Greetings from Chile.

Comment: @MrRoman -- De nada. Fue un placer. Saludos de Sudafrica. ;-)